# How to make the jQuery autocomplete text area into a form field?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I got the jQuery autocomplete form mostly working how I need it to work here: http://problemio.com/test.php

but there is one problem:  I can't get the area where the chosen items are listed to be a form field.  Right now it is just some uneditable text area and when I try to do a

```
var log = $("#log").val();
```

that gets nothing in the value, so I can't really submit it.

1) How do I make that area into a form field whose value can be retrieved upon form submission?
2) Also, how do people manage to allow the users to remove the items they had chosen?

Thanks!!

Comment: what about ${'#log'}.text(); ?

Comment: Why not make it a textarea then? You could get the contents of your div by doing a .text()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get the value of a `div` element (there isn't one). That's what you're trying to do in your #add_category click handler on line 75 (`$("#log").val()` -- #log is a div)

You need to get the html or text from the div:

```
// change line 75 to 
$("#log").html()
// or
$("#log").text()
```

**OR**

You can just change the html of the `log` area with a textarea:

```
//change
<div id="log" style="height: 200px; width: 300px; overflow: auto;" class="ui-widget-content"></div>

// to
<textarea id="log" style="height: 200px; width: 300px; overflow: auto;" class="ui-widget-content"></textarea>
```

Comment: I see.  Ok trying your ideas now.  Will report back in a couple of minutes :)

Answer (score 0):

To make the selected value go into a field you need to change the `log()` function to record it. You also need to make some means of removing the input, afterwards. Something like:

```
function log( message ) 
{
    $( "input[type=submit]" ).after('<input type="text" name="chosenvalues[]" value="' + message + '" readonly="readonly" /><span class="remover">Remove</span>');
    $( ".remover:last" ).click(function () {
        $(this).prev("input").remove();
    });
}
```